# SQL single table with two columns

Tags: sql

I have a single table: Checking, with two columns: ID, Memo

ID is the primary key.

I would like a query that returns both columns: ID, Memo BUT only where Memo is DISTINCT

I can do the following to get the distinct values from Memo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(memo)
FROM checking
```

How do I return those Memo values and their values from the ID column?

I've run in circles trying inner and outer joins but I'm failing.

Thanks for your help

Sample data:

```
ID        Memo
1         a
2         c
3         e
4         g
5         a
6         c
```

The desired return:

```
1,a
2,c
3,e
4,g
```

5 and 6 would not be included because they have duplicate memo values.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Is ID Unique?  Can two different IDs share the same Memo value?  If they can then you cannot retrieve one ID for a Distinct Memo.

Comment: Could you provide example data and expected output to demonstrate your issue?  The database being used would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the **first** (?) primary key value corresponding to each unique memo value found?  (I'm assuming this because you can't logically have both unique memos and Id values because there is necessarily multiple ID values for each duplicated memo value...)  If the assumption is correct this will work:

```
SELECT m.memo, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 x.id
     FROM checking x
     WHERE x.memo = m.memo
     ORDER BY x.id) as ID
FROM checking m
GROUP BY m.memo
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much for your help.  I never would have gotten this.

Answer (score 4):

SELECT  min(id), memo 
FROM checking 
group by memo

Comment: +1 I agree, it's easier to look at and **MIN** would do just as well here

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID,MEMO from CHECKING WHERE ID IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM CHECKING WHERE MEMO IN (SELECT DISTINCT MEMO FROM CHECKING))

Though nested, this query would server the purpose!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,memo
FROM test
WHERE id IN
   (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM test
    WHERE memo IN 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT memo
        FROM test
        )
    GROUP BY memo
   )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, memo
from checking
join 
( /*only where Memo is DISTINCT*/
  select distinct(memo) as memo
  from checking
) as m on checking.memo = m.memo
```

Comment: This still returns duplicate values in the memo column.

I agree with you though, this should do the trick but it doesn't.